# Explain why the following conditions should be satisfied for a sustained interference

Tags: optics, interference

My Book says that

The following conditions should be satisfied for a sustained interference

> 1. The two coherent sources placed in front of two slits separated by some distance should be close to each other so as to produce a sustained interference on the screen kept at some distance from the slits
> 2. Amplitude of incoming waves should be equal
> 3. The two sources should be strong with least background

I have got the following justification for the upper given point

- For the first point maybe if the current sources are not close to each other than the phase difference changes continuously and won't give interferance
- according to me the second point is wrong because even if the amplitude of waves are not equal still I have seen interference pattern forming
- I didn't understand the third point

Please help me

Comment: Which book? ___

Comment: Which book? Can you give an author and full title, or a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that they give "practical conditions" to observe interferences :
If the two slit are too far apart, the fringes will be too close to be easily observed (the interfringe is lambda*D/a and a is too great). Moreover there will be a problem with the spatial coherence of the source witch illuminate the slits.
If the amplitude are too differents, the contrast of the fringes will be low.
If there is highly illuminated background, you will not see the fringe (low contrast !)
Hope you can understand my poor enblish !

Comment: Hey in the first point you have talked about two slits where is in my question I have talked about distance between two coherent sources please correct that thanks for the answer

Comment: @DavidWax You are talking about Young's Double Slit Experiment right? It required only one coherent source not two.

Comment: I thought that the two slits were the two "coherent sources" ? I dont understand why they would speak of  two slits illuminated by two coherent sources ?